# Is it possible to return null for an optional capture group in a regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am using Ruby to break a version number from a system up into its constiuent parts. There are two formats that need to be considered:

```
  type version (date)
  type date
```

I have got a regualr expression for this which can handle the fact that the `version` is not always present. It is `^([^\s]+)\s([^\s]+)?\s?\(?(.*?)\)?$\`.

However although this works the optional capture group is not present when the `version` is not in the string, which makes sense. For example (output from Ruby):

```
['type', 'version', 'date']
['type', 'date', '']
```

Is there any way to make the RegEx return a null for the optional capture group when it is not there? The output would then be:

```
['type', 'version', 'date']
['type', '', 'date']
```

Comment: That's not "null", that's the empty string.

Comment: Also, where's your Ruby code?

Comment: Once you define a capturing group in a regex pattern, even if it is not participating in the match, the item will still be added to the output array of group values.

Comment: `NULL` is not defined in Ruby. Methods return objects. Specify which object or objects can be returned (e.g., `nil`, `''`, `true`, `false`, `74`, and so on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `regex` to match both formats:

```
/^(\S+)\s+(?:(\S+)\s+\((\S+)\)|(\S+))$/
```

I used `\S` instead of `[^\s]`. They have the [same meaning](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes) (any non-space character) but `\S` is shorter and easier to read.

#### The expression piece by piece

```
/             # regex delimiter
^             # match the start of the string
(\S+)         # capturing group that matches one or more non-space characters (type)
\s+           # one or more space characters
(?:           # start of a non-capturing group
              #   +--- alternative #1: format "type version (date)"
   (\S+)      #   | capturing group for version 
   \s+        #   |
   \(         #   | match a literal '('
   (\S+)      #   | capturing group for date
   \)         #   | match a literal ')'
              #   +-------------------
|             # OR - either match alternative #1 or alternative #2
              #   +--- alternative #2: format "type date"
   (\S+)      #   | capturing group for date
              #   +-------------------
)             # end of the non-capturing group
$             # match the end of the string
/             # regex delimiter
```

Matching strings against this `regex` produce:

```
irb (main)> "Type Version (Date)".match(/^(\S+)\s+(?:(\S+)\s+\((\S+)\)|(\S+))$/)
=> #<MatchData "Type Version (Date)" 1:"Type" 2:"Version" 3:"Date" 4:nil>

irb(main)> "Type Date".match(/^(\S+)\s+(?:(\S+)\s+\((\S+)\)|(\S+))$/)
=> #<MatchData "Type Date" 1:"Type" 2:nil 3:nil 4:"Date">
```

There are 4 items in the resulting `MatchData` object because there are 4 capturing groups in the `regex`. The groups present in the alternatives are added up, those from the non-matching alternative are set to `nil`.

The next step is to [name the capturing groups](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Capturing). This way we can identify them easier and also identify (and collapse) the alternatives.

Now the `regex` is:

```
/^(?<type>\S+)\s+(?:(?<version>\S+)\s+\((?<date>\S+)\)|(?<date>\S+))$/
```

and produces:

```
irb(main)> "Type Version (Date)".match(/^(?<type>\S+)\s+(?:(?<version>\S+)\s+\((?<date>\S+)\)|(?<date>\S+))$/)
=> #<MatchData "Type Version (Date)" type:"Type" version:"Version" date:"Date" date:nil>

irb(main)> "Type Date".match(/^(?<type>\S+)\s+(?:(?<version>\S+)\s+\((?<date>\S+)\)|(?<date>\S+))$/)
=> #<MatchData "Type Date" type:"Type" version:nil date:nil date:"Date">
```

The last step is to use the method [`MatchData#named_captures`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/MatchData.html#method-i-named_captures) to get the matched pieces in a [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html) that contains the correct values for `date`, according to the matched alternative.

#### The final result

```
irb(main)> "Type Version (Date)".match(/^(?<type>\S+)\s+(?:(?<version>\S+)\s+\((?<date>\S+)\)|(?<date>\S+))$/).named_captures
=> {"type"=>"Type", "version"=>"Version", "date"=>"Date"}

irb(main)> "Type Date".match(/^(?<type>\S+)\s+(?:(?<version>\S+)\s+\((?<date>\S+)\)|(?<date>\S+))$/).named_captures
=> {"type"=>"Type", "version"=>nil, "date"=>"Date"}
```

#### Extra

If you need to get an empty string and not `nil` for `version` on format #2 you can add an empty capturing group named `version` on the second alternative, before the `date` group:

```
/^(?<type>\S+)\s+(?:(?<version>\S+)\s+\((?<date>\S+)\)|(?<version>)(?<date>\S+))$/
```

Comment: A good answer to the question... but I would slap any developer that tries to use that regex in anything but a one-off hack.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for functionality where:

```
type version (date)
type date
```

results in:

```
['type', 'version', 'date']
['type',          , 'date']
```

you probably want to use an *non-capturing group* like `(?:version)`
as well as `(version)|` as in  `(?:(version)|)`, this will allow you to either capture something or capture 'nothing/null/nil'

Try out this regular expression:

```
^([^\s]+)\s(?:([^\s]*)\s|)\(?(.*)\)?$
```

I recommend using http://regex101.com to understand what the different symbols mean.

Comment: Doesn't actually match `type date`. Did you not try it? Also, `['type',          , 'date']` isn't valid.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, `['type',  ,'date']` is not valid ruby. Note that in some implementations of regex matching, arrays are poor representations of capture data, eg in this example there may not exist a second capture at all, using 'nil' might be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Regex free zone.

```
strs = [
  'type version (date)',
  'type date'
]

results = strs.map do |str|
  type, *version, date = str.split
  [type, version[0].to_s, date.tr('()', '')]
end

p results


--output:--
[["type", "version", "date"], ["type", "", "date"]]
```

If you would rather have `nil` than a blank string, then remove the `to_s`. Having `nil` in there would allow you to write something like:

```
if arr[1]
   #do one thing
else
   #do another thing
```

Because a blank string is considered `true` in ruby, the if-branch would always execute if the array has a blank string at index 1.  The only things considered false in ruby are `nil` and `false`.